# Wi-Fi adapter Realtek RTL8192CU slow speed connection ~0,5 mbit

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have a Wi-Fi adapter Wi-Fi adapter Realtek RTL8192CU. However, I am getting very slow speed, like ~0,5 mbit.

How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to install any drivers from GitHub (it won't work).

The problem is that the system has two drivers. (rtl8xxxu and rtl8192cu)
Old one **(rtl8192cu)** should be turned off to turn on a new one **(rtl8xxxu)** that is already built into the Linux kernel.

Let's see it:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

Let's blacklist the last one:

```
sudo -i 
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Then restart your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: FWIW, this worked perfectly for me on Linux Mint (makes sense; derived from Ubuntu).  Didn't work on Solus (because a necessary kernel config parameter was missing) or Manjaro (for reasons I never understood).  And while the GitHub repo that I think was referenced above (https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) may not be directly useful (it's deprecated), the README is worth a look for anyone with this problem.